# Set css color based on a range

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm generating a random number between 0 and 180 cycling every 4 seconds, successfully.

I need to set a div's background-color based on the random number. like

between 0 and 60 set css color to red, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)

between 61 and 120 green, rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.0)

between 121 and 180 blue, rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)

So it all has to hinge on the variable... Any ideas...

Comment: I'm assuming you're generating the random number via JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: What did you try so far? You haven't added any code. To change the color, you could use `$('divselector').css('background', 'rgba(...)')` and set the value inside rgba based on specific condition for the variable. Or build the rgba string before and just set it inside `.css`. And since you're just using plain red, green and blue, you could make it much simpler than using whole `rgba` notation, eve using the color names would work.

Comment: Thanks, using JQuery..   Haven't added anything to try to change the color yet...  My code generates a variable

Answer (score 1):

Run this code and click on box to get random colors

```js
    $(window).ready(function() {

  $('#background').click(function() {

    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 180) + 0);
   console.log("random number is: "+ number);
    if (number <= 60) {
      $(this).css('backgroundColor', "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)")

    } else if (number <= 120) {
      $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.0)');
    } else {
      $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)');
    }

  });
})
```

```css
#background {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background"></div>
```

Comment: @Daniel Canna, Run code snippet to test what you needed, if it is still not as you required please let me know, Thanks

Comment: if you are having difficulty in understanding this code please ask

Comment: Thanks Nick, Edgar, and Muhammad.... I think this gets me there.. Much appreciated... :-)

Comment: now I get your complete question just give me few more mins

Comment: I had added click event so you can check random number on run time, now i added console.log so you can see in real time, also added checks that you asked for based on that random number

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's generally best to include your code in your S.O question to give your question some context.

That being said, the following should help you:

```
var ran // your random number
if (ran < 60) {
  $("div selector").css("color", "your color value here");
} else if (ran < 120) {
  $("div selector").css("color", "your color value here");
}
```

So on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (number <= 60) {
  $('#my-div').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)');
} else if (number <= 120) {
  $('#my-div').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.0)');
} else {
  $('#my-div').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)');
}
```

... but, is this an answer? I guess, I didn't get your question well.

Comment: I Think that's EXACTLY it... Thank You!  Being new to jQuery the syntax is still pretty new to me...  So to write that on my own.. I would have made a bunch of mistakes..

Comment: It always triggers the else ... It's gotta be syntax.    in my case number is a variable called changingSpeed...        if ('#changingSpeed' <= 60) {
  $('#meter_box').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.2 )');

Comment: tried            if (changingSpeed <= 60) {
  $('#meter_box').css('background-color', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1.2 )');